# Regexp to get text what is inside the parentheses and separated by a colon

Tags: regex

I am not strong in regular expressions.
I need to get index of text what is inside the parentheses and separated by a colon.
For example, this is my text

```
Lenovo EasyCamera (0c45:6310)
```

Incorrect regexp

```
var pattern:RegExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/g;
var indexOfPattern:int = mediaName.search(pattern);
```

In case of

```
Lenovo EasyCamera (0c45:6310) XSB (szbvd)
```

the regexp finds both (0c45:6310)  and (szbvd). But i need only (0c45:6310).

Help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\(([^)]+:[^)]+)\)
```

You can simply do this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/aI4rA5/5